# Одинарная кавычка в t-sql

Tags: sql-server

**Добрый день!**

Имеется динамический t-sql код:

```
select a from table1
where field1 = val
```

Все работает, если `val` - это число. Но если строка, то необходимо как-то программно проставить одинарные кавычки перед val и после него (наприм. where field1 = **'new_val'**)

**Помогите пожалуйста, как правильно экранировать одинарные кавычки!**

Спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

Необходимо заменить одну кавычки на две.

Comment: вы правы. у меня синтаксическая ошибка в коде, поэтому и ругалось. спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

Не делайте так - это потенциальный источник множества неприятных ошибок, которые будут наровить возникнуть при модификации вашего кода в будущем.

Вместо этого правильнее использовать параметризованые запросы.

В чистом T-SQL для их создания используется системная хранимая процедура [sp_prepare](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff848808.aspx).

В большинстве же конекторов для прикладных языков программирования используются обертки над sp_prepare, которые позволяют просто передавать масив либо словарь с переменными произвольных типов при вызове метода создания или выполнения запроса.